# apply javascript to all images with same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

The JavaScript below only replaces the src for one image on a page how can i get it to do it for multiple images on the same page

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

loadImage1 = new Image();
loadImage1.src = "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Xzm-yUJ_dz0/Tsj3Q57J2tI/AAAAAAAAAGE/bohLMRj5FCY/s1600/hover.png";

staticImage1 = new Image();
staticImage1.src = "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/--0FurTdrYzg/Tsj3RPXGz4I/AAAAAAAAAGI/mm_4UvmoD-A/s1600/standard.png";

replaceImage1 = new Image();
replaceImage1.src = "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-oacZCbBUhQ0/Tsj3Qkl4IaI/AAAAAAAAAGA/5_z-2VXKCi8/s1600/clicked.png";

</script>
```

The Image HTML is below if required.I don't mind applying and ID or CLASS to the images either :)

```
<img onMouseOver="image1.src=loadImage1.src;" onMouseOut="image1.src=staticImage1.src;" onmousedown="image1.src=replaceImage1.src;" onmouseup="image1.src=loadImage1.src;" style=width:480px;height:360px;background-image:url('http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/XtNcZnfkL2A/hqdefault.jpg');" name="image1" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/--0FurTdrYzg/Tsj3RPXGz4I/AAAAAAAAAGI/mm_4UvmoD-A/s1600/standard.png">
```

**AND/OR is there a cleaner jquery for this I would much rather use jQuery, thankyou!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as:
Add a class to images , like;

```
<img class='someclass' ....
```

Then using jQuery you can select all the images having the same classname, like;

```
$("img[class='someClass']").each(function() {
   //replace src attribute of each image
   $(this).attr("src", "");
   $(this).attr("src", "your_new_src");
});
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

If you'd rather do it with jQuery, you can select all the images by name using an "[attribute equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)" selector:

```
$("img[name='image1']").attr("src", "newImageSource.png");
```

If you would like to add a class attribute to the images, you can use a class selector:

```
$(".someClass").attr("src", "newImageSource.png");
```

The `attr` method will apply to all elements matching the selector, so there's no need to iterate over the matched set.